# Large file processing performance

Tags: text-processing, regular-expression, python, performance, csv

I did a simple performance test of csv processing a while ago, and want to share results with community, maybe you can point out, what test could be more precise and fair.

Firstly i took out 42 MB `csv` file, that looked like this:

[image: csv data]

First part of image is real contents of the `csv` file, then second contains rows, that i would like to process. The principle is:
`If 3rd column contains "out" in the end of cell, then sum 5th coulumn`

Here is how much various tools took time to process this file:

```
AWK                          AWK                           AWK
---                          ---                           ---
real    0m0.627s             real   0m0.626s           real 0m0.631s
user    0m0.627s             user   0m0.614s           user 0m0.611s
sys     0m0.000s             sys    0m0.012s           sys  0m0.020s

PERL                         PERL                          PERL
----                         ----                          ----
real    0m0.931s             real   0m0.946s           real 0m0.933s
user    0m0.927s             user   0m0.941s           user 0m0.929s
sys     0m0.004s             sys    0m0.004s           sys  0m0.004s

BASH                         BASH                          BASH
------                       ------                        ------
real    0m0.186s             real   0m0.173s           real 0m0.184s
user    0m0.318s             user   0m0.336s           user 0m0.311s
sys     0m0.022s             sys    0m0.022s           sys  0m0.022s

PYTHON2                      PYTHON2                       PYTHON2
------                       ------                        ------
real    0m1.164s             real   0m1.191s           real 0m1.163s
user    0m1.144s             user   0m1.162s           user 0m1.155s
sys     0m0.020s             sys    0m0.028s           sys  0m0.008s

PYTHON3                      PYTHON3                       PYTHON3
------                       ------                        ------
real    0m1.377s             real   0m1.392s           real 0m1.377s
user    0m1.361s             user   0m1.380s           user 0m1.377s
sys     0m0.016s             sys    0m0.012s           sys  0m0.000s

AWK sum is 2181681           AWK sum is 2181681        AWK sum is 2181681
PERL sum is 2181681          PERL sum is 2181681       PERL sum is 2181681
BASH sum is 2181681          BASH sum is 2181681       BASH sum is 2181681
PYTHON2 sum is 2181681       PYTHON2 sum is 2181681    PYTHON2 sum is 2181681
PYTHON3 sum is 2181681       PYTHON3 sum is 2181681    PYTHON3 sum is 2181681
```

(Also i concatenated this file 3 times and got 126 MB of data, which resulted in tripled time)

Bash is winner, next is AWK and in the third place is Perl (but i read that [Perl is outperforming AWK and SED](http://rc3.org/2014/08/28/surprisingly-perl-outperforms-sed-and-awk/), is my file not big enought?).

What is slightly amazed me, is what python 3 is **slower**, than python 2. Why is that?

P.S. The script i used is posted [here](https://pastebin.com/1F3rni71). 
Here is also is upper bound of my laptop file processing (as was in [this](http://rc3.org/2014/08/28/surprisingly-perl-outperforms-sed-and-awk/) article)

```
time cat atbats.csv > /dev/null 

real    0m0.013s
user    0m0.001s
sys     0m0.012s
```

Comment: There is no indication as to what CVS parsing library was used.  Would the test even run for a CSV file containing fields with embedded commas and/or newlines?  If not, then the performance in parsing is unimportant and what you measure is merely the speed in which a language is able to split a string on commas.

Comment: locale can also make a huge difference in performance.  try running your timing tests with `LC_ALL=C` if unicode characters aren't important in your data.

Comment: If you're looking for performance, you might want to check with an OLAP DBMS such as DuckDB which run in-memory SQL requests on million-lines CSV files in no time